# Simple issue with meta-tags gem when rendering page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, meta-tags

I'm trying to use meta-tags gem for Rails 4. In their docs they say to put the meta tags as for example:

```
set_meta_tags :title => 'Member Login'
```

So I suppose this goes in my view with the following sintax

```
<%= set_meta_tags :title => 'Member Login' %>
```

However when refreshing the page, I get the metatags rendered as plain text.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of `=` after `<%`. Get rid of it and text won't show up.

Separate note, you can just use:

```
<% title 'Member Login' %>
```

Comment: And how about if I want to use photo.title for example? Do I need to interpole it? <% title "The photo called #{photo.title}" %> . Is this sintax correct?

Comment: Syntax should be correct, assuming you have `photo` object defined.

Comment: I saw for this gem you need to use display_meta_tags in view. Everything working. Thanks for your time